# How can i change add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' ); this hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, action

In my themes exist plugin how registering 10 custom post type with add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' );I want change it and registr only 2.

I try remove this with remove_action() and writh new action, but have errors, Fatal error: Cannot redeclare like_add_custom_post_types() (previously declared in ....(plugin path)
//////this plugin code

```
    function like_add_custom_post_types() {

        $cpt = array(

            'testimonials'  => true,
            'sliders'       => true,
            'sections'      => true,
            'events'        => true,
            'menu'          => true,
            'gallery'       => true,
            'team'          => true,
            'faq'           => true,
        );

        foreach ($cpt as $item => $enabled) {

            $cpt_include = likeGetLocalPath( '/post_types/' . $item . '/' . $item . '.php' );
            if ( $enabled AND file_exists( $cpt_include ) ) {

                include_once $cpt_include;
            }
        }   
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' );


    function like_rewrite_flush() {
        like_add_custom_post_types();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

  ///////// my code 
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_theme_stuff', 0 );

    function remove_parent_theme_stuff() {

        remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' );
    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme',"like_add_custom_post_types");


    function like_add_custom_post_types() {





                include_once ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/like-themes-plugins/post_types/sections/sections.php';


    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Search function called `like_add_custom_post_types` in theme. Given error says function with name `like_add_custom_post_types` is already in theme.

How to solve :

- change a function name to something else.
- If you want to remove 8 post type then find function and comment `register_post_type`

  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'like_add_custom_post_types' );

Comment: You need remove post type is the question